# Does the limit : $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\ln x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sin x}$ exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, limsup-and-liminf

I tried to evaluate the limit

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\ln x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sin x}$$ but came to the conclusion that the limit would not exist as $\sin x$ changes sign too frequently so obviously limit cannot exist.

Can there be a more concrete argument

Comment: Of course. Let $x_n = (2n+1) \pi$ and show that one subsequence causes the value to go to $+\infty$ and another to $-\infty$.

Comment: The informal version of @copper.hat's comment is "the numerator diverges to infinity while the denominator alternates in parity, so the limit oscillates between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$"

Comment: The expression is not even *defined* for all (sufficiently) large $x$.

Comment: Take $x_n = n\pi \pm \arcsin(1/n)$.  @MartinR one can ask the question in ${\mathbb R}\setminus\pi{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Can you please elaborate further

Comment: @Gribouillis In what meaningful sense is taking a limit to infinity valid in the order topology of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\pi\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Minor quibble.  Did you mean $ln(x^\frac{1}{3})$ or $(ln(x))^\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg It is $ln(x^\frac{1}{3})$

Comment: Also, I goofed, the expression is undefined for the value of $x_n$ I gave above, I meant $(2n+1) { \pi \over 2}$. As @MartinR pointed out, the expression is not defined for integral multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: $ln(x^\frac{1}{3})=\frac{ln(x)}{3}$.  Why the complication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \left(x\right) = \frac{\ln  {x}^{1/3}}{\sin  \left(x\right)}$. We have

\begin{equation}\liminf\limits _{\substack{x \rightarrow  \infty \\
x \notin  {\pi} \mathbb{Z}
}} f \left(x\right)  \leqslant  \lim _{n \rightarrow  \infty } f \left(n {\pi}-\arcsin  \left(1/n\right)\right) = \lim _{n \rightarrow  \infty } \frac{\ln  {\left(n {\pi}-\arcsin  \left(1/n\right)\right)}^{1/3}}{{-1}/n} =-\infty \end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}\limsup\limits _{\substack{x \rightarrow  \infty \\
x \notin  {\pi} \mathbb{Z}
}} f \left(x\right)  \geqslant  \lim _{n \rightarrow  \infty } f \left(n {\pi}+\arcsin  \left(1/n\right)\right) = \lim _{n \rightarrow  \infty } \frac{\ln  {\left(n {\pi}+\arcsin  \left(1/n\right)\right)}^{1/3}}{1/n} =+\infty \end{equation}

Hence $f \left(x\right)$ has no limit when $x \rightarrow  \infty  , x \notin  {\pi} \mathbb{Z}$.